# Unexpected behavior from datalist in vue while using vue directives (v-model, @input) on input field?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, html-datalist

Basically I've written following snippet in which I am using v-model in input that has datalist. When I select one of the datalist, **datalist immediately reappears again** after I select a option as if I had manually typed the code.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    input: '',
    list : [
    {name:"Item 1", code:"i1"},
    {name:"Item 2", code:"i2"},
    {name:"Item 3", code:"i3"},
    {name:"Item 4", code:"i4"},
    ]
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <p>{{ input }}</p>
  <input v-model="input" list="list" />
  <datalist id="list">
    <option v-for="item in list" :value="item.code">{{item.name}}</option>
  </datalist>
</div>
```

**But** this does not happen when I remove vue directive from the input field (v-model,@input).  I've added both code for convenience. I hope someone will help me because I need v-moder if not @input in my input field.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    input: '',
    list : [
    {name:"Item 1", code:"i1"},
    {name:"Item 2", code:"i2"},
    {name:"Item 3", code:"i3"},
    {name:"Item 4", code:"i4"},
    ]
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <p>{{ input }}</p>
  <input list="list" />
  <datalist id="list">
    <option v-for="item in list" :value="item.code">{{item.name}}</option>
  </datalist>
</div>
```

**EDIT** As suggested by @muka.gergely I used external method to blur the input field *after value was selected*. It is not perfect solution, but works as expected. (probably bug in chrome). Here is code

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    input: '',
    list: [{
        name: "Item 1",
        code: "i1"
      },
      {
        name: "Item 2",
        code: "i2"
      },
      {
        name: "Item 3",
        code: "i3"
      },
      {
        name: "Item 4",
        code: "i4"
      },
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    onSelect(event) {
      let val = event.target.value;
      let select = false;
      let options = document.getElementById("list").childNodes;
      for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
        //check if value in input box is one of the options
        if (options[i].value === val.trim()) {
          //value was selected
          //do something
          select = true;
          //bluring input field so as not to show datalist again
          event.target.blur();
          break;
        }
      }
      //value was typed
      if (!select) {
        //this.fetchAutocomplete(val);
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <p>{{ input }}</p>
  <input v-model="input" list="list" @input="onSelect" />
  <datalist id="list">
    <option v-for="item in list" :value="item.code">{{item.name}}</option>
  </datalist>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code works as you wrote it:

1. `<p>{{input}}</p>` - this is the first line. On init it's empty, so now lines are shown.
2. `<input v-model="input" list="list" />` this is the second line, but on init it is displayed first.

So, when your app reacts to data change, the `input` is pushed one line down. If you initialize your `input` data with something else than `''`, then you can see that nothing unexpected happens (OK, maybe unexpected, but not extraordinary :) ):

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    input: '',
    list: [{
        name: "Item 1",
        code: "i1"
      },
      {
        name: "Item 2",
        code: "i2"
      },
      {
        name: "Item 3",
        code: "i3"
      },
      {
        name: "Item 4",
        code: "i4"
      },
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    loseFocus(evt) {
      evt.target.blur()
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <p>{{ input || 'Data comes here' }}</p>
  <input v-model="input" list="list" @input="loseFocus" />
  <datalist id="list">
    <option v-for="item in list" :value="item.code">{{item.name}}</option>
  </datalist>
</div>
```

## EDIT

The problem was not the "jumping" of the input, but that the datalist appeared open after picking an option.

The problem is that this element stays focused after the input/change event, so it behaves in an unwanted way. (But as it's supposed to behave.)

I added `@input` on the element, and created a `method` to blur the element (so it loses focus, and the datalist doesn't open/closes).

## 2nd EDIT

We discussed the question a bit more in the chat, and came up a with a snippet that is closer to the actual solution @KshitijDhakal sought:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    input: '',
    list: [{
        type: 'posts',
        title: 'Posts',
        code: 'i1'
      },
      {
        type: 'albums',
        title: 'Albums',
        code: 'i2'
      }
    ],
    singleItem: {
      title: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    fetchData: function(type, id) {
      return fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/${type}/${id}`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => {
          return json
        })
    },
    onSelect: async function(e) {
      if (this.list.map(el => el.code).includes(e.target.value)) e.target.blur()
      this.singleItem = await this.fetchData(this.list.find(el => el.code === e.target.value).type, 1)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input v-model="input" list="list" @input="onSelect" />
  <datalist id="list">
    <option v-for="item in list" :value="item.code">{{item.title}}</option>
  </datalist>
  <div>
    <h2>
      {{singleItem.title}}
    </h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I get what you are implying, but that is not the problem. I am using chrome v 77.0 and problem still persists even in your answer.

Comment: Oh, OK, just a bit of misreading - so the problem is that the datalist is open?

Comment: @KshitijDhakal I edited the snippet, so it doesn't open the datalist after picking an option. I used `HTMLelement.blur()` at the `@input=""` event

Comment: sorry, but it's not what I am looking for. What I am trying to achieve is to fetch autocompleteList from db on input event in input field. That part wasn't difficult at all with fetch and all, but using your method input field becomes unusable as it loses focus everytime I enter something.

Comment: But I think I might be able to work around it with your solution (using external method to check if value was selected or typed and then use focusout). Thanks for answer although not exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Thank you for the upvote! This function is simple, and - yeah - it blurs on every input event. Not too convenient, I know, just wanted to show that it can be done. And sorry, if I didn’t get the problem right! :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201265/discussion-between-kshitij-dhakal-and-muka-gergely).